# Proving that $\lim|a_n|=|\lim a_n|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

I know that $|A|=|\Bbb R|$ for $A=(a,b); a\ne b; a,b\in\Bbb R$(where $|\cdot |$ is the size of the set $\cdot$) and I know how to prove it by mapping $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to $\Bbb R$.

Few days ago I thought about a different way to prove this using sequences. I did the following:

map $(0,1)$ to $(b,a+b)$ using the function $f(x)=ax+b$, because $b,a$ are arbitrary  I have $|(a,b)|=|(c,d)|$.

Now for the sequence $a_n=|(-n,n)|$ we have $a_i=a_j;j,i\in\Bbb N$.

More over $|\lim_{n\to\infty}(-n,n)|=|\Bbb R|$.

So I have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}|(-n,n)|$, but how can I show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|(-n,n)|=|\lim_{n\to\infty}(-n,n)|$?

Again, I am well aware about other ways to prove that the size of the real numbers is equal to the size of a subset.

Comment: Limiting a sequence of sets is not a [simple endeavor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross–Littlewood_paradox) and should only be done with extreme caution.

Comment: How do you define $|\mathbb{R}|$? It's easy to show something has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, but how do you define the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ itself alone? Your argument can be made rigorous using measure theory provided that you can find a measure that gives the appropriate interpretation, but I'm not sure if it's possible and in any case, I think you should find come up with a meaning for $|\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: @stressed-out Don't add confusion to the confusion, please. Measure theory in the sense it is introduced for functional analysis would be completely out of place for an argument of cardinality.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Why? :D  $m(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-n,n)) = \lim_{n\to\ \infty} m((-n,n))$ seems to hold true if we can find a good measure. No? + there's the counting measure that works for finite sets. I'm not saying that it's possible to find such a measure though.

Comment: @stressed-out I think it's up to you to provide a reference for cardinal-valued measure theory. I don't feel like dealing in that.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: I never claimed such a thing existed. I'm just saying that the problem can be put in the language of measure theory. That's all.

Comment: @stressed-out Problems of cardinality behave rather differently from problems of measure.

Comment: $$\Large\textbf{CARDINALS ARE NOT REAL NUMBERS!!!}$$

Comment: @AsafKaragila what do you mean? im asking how to prove that the limit of a size of set is equal to the size of the limit of the set

Comment: First tell me, how do you define the limit of cardinals?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Is it possible to define the cardinal of $\mathbb{R}$ in the first place? I mean it's certainly possible to compare the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ with other sets, but can it be defined on its own alone?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have the sequence $a_n=|(-n,n)|$, so if I take the limit is have $\lim|(-n,n)|$ no? Why is it not well defined?

Comment: @Masacroso normally I would agree with you, but this is true because absolute value is continuous, but here the notation of $|\cdot|$ represent a size of a set, not absolute value, farther more the sequence is the size of the subsets of $\Bbb R$, which is equal $\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$, and like Asaf said, this is not a real number, so the normal approach with limits won't work here

Comment: You keep saying "you take the limit". This has to be defined. I want to know how *you* define that operation on cardinals. Yes, there is a definition, but I think you don't know it, and I think you are treating cardinals like they were real numbers.

Comment: @stressed-out: I don't even know how to answer that. How is this remark not valid for $\varnothing$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: well, you can define the cardinality of the emptyset to be $0$ by definition. But you're right, even for finite sets we'll have a problem.